# Obtaining an average from if statement Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok so I got everything figured out. But now I am trying to use an if statement to tell the loop to take the average mpg (from the .txt file) from vehicles that get less than 22 mpg and then just average that up and output it IDLE. I feel like I should run the if statement before the loop. I am just not sure what I really need to change. I figure I should be able to slice variable holding the text file data. anyways here is my code. Can someone help me understand what I am not doing right?

```
def cityGasGuzzler():
# Input:that assigns a text file to a value and provides other definition 
 values
cityGuzz = open("carModelData_city.","r")
# Process: For loop to get average of gas guzzling city street driving 
  vehicles
for line in cityGuzz:
# Process: Uses if statement to get the average of lower mpg or gas guzzlers
    if cityGuzz[0:-1] < 22:
        sum = sum + eval(line)
        count = count + 1
        avrg = sum / count
# Output: using the round function to get average to the 2nd decimal place
#         and prints string and rounded variable to IDLE.
print("The average city MPG is,", round(avrg, 2))



cityGasGuzzler()
```

Just to clarify, my main objective is as follows, take the numeric values from the text file that are less than 22, average those up and output the average to IDLE.

Comment: *"I believe will return append with float values"* - that's not correct, and it's unclear why you thought otherwise. `for i in len(text1).readline` - ...what?

Comment: @jonrsharpe well the values in the text file are floats. And as far as the loop goes, I am just trying to figure to get this figured out so I can get expected results.

Comment: They *represent* floats, but I've no idea what you thought `float()` on its own would do. I'd strongly recommend some more structured learning, see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, your issue is with this line:

```
if cityGuzz[0:-1] < 22:
```

That's not working for several reasons, not least because `cityGuzz` is the file object, not the current line. You need to convert the current line into a number before comparing it with a number like `22`.

Try something like this:

```
total = 0 # renamed to avoid masking the builtin sum function
count = 0

for line in cityGuzz:
    mpg = float(line)
    if mpg < 22:
        total += mpg
        count += 1

average = total / count
```

I renamed `sum` to `total` because `sum` is the name of a builtin function. In fact, it might be a useful one to replace the explicit loop to add up the values from the file. Here's an alternative implementation of the average calculation:

```
guzzlers = [mpg for mpg in map(float, cityGuzz) if mpg < 22]
average = sum(guzzlers) / len(guzzlers)
```

Comment: Thank you! the top worked, I will give the bottom a try as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to divide to quantity in each iteration of loop. Also you have several mistakes in your code. Try this out.

```
sum = 0.0
quantity = 0
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readline():
        if line.isdigit():
            sum += float(line)
            quantity += 1
average = sum/quantity
print average
```

Comment: this worked but I got a low number output into IDLE. Any chance there is a more basic way to code this?

Comment: @Woop, this is pretty basic piece of code. You have to practice more in programming in general. Try to read python documentations and APIs, if they are not clear probably you need to have a basic course on programming on any language.

Comment: Yes roger that. I am taking a CS class and learning python, but I am also taking chemistry as well and chemistry is far harder and taking up most my time. I am going to review a lot of my CS class while on break. Plus I am building a budge it program. So be ready to see posts asking for help with that. Thanks again for your help!